# ruby regex to match multiple occurrences of pattern

Tags: ruby, regex

I am looking to build a ruby regex to match multiple occurrences of a pattern and return them in an array. The pattern is simply: [[.+]]. That is, two left brackets, one or more characters, followed by two right brackets.

This is what I have done:

```
str = "Some random text[[lead:first_name]] and more stuff [[client:last_name]]"
str.match(/\[\[(.+)\]\]/).captures
```

The regex above doesn't work because it returns this:

```
["lead:first_name]] and another [[client:last_name"]
```

When what I wanted was this:

```
["lead:first_name", "client:last_name"]
```

I thought if I used a noncapturing group that for sure it should solve the issue:

```
str.match(/(?:\[\[(.+)\]\])+/).captures
```

But the noncapturing group returns the same exact wrong output. Any idea on how I can resolve my issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Try this`](http://rubular.com/r/mbpiW8ojMg):

```
 => str.match(/\[\[(.*)\]\].*\[\[(.*)\]\]/).captures
 => ["lead:first_name", "client:last_name"]
```

[`With many occurrences`](http://rubular.com/r/v4AN4vnfgM):

```
 => str
 => "Some [[lead:first_name]] random text[[lead:first_name]] and more [[lead:first_name]] stuff [[client:last_name]]" 
 => str.scan(/\[(\w+:\w+)\]/)
 => [["lead:first_name"], ["lead:first_name"], ["lead:first_name"], ["client:last_name"]]
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand your regex. The only issue is that it would match two occurrences, but not n occurrences where n could be 3 or 4 or 5 occurrences in the string.

Answer (score 8):

The problem with your regex is that the `.+` part is "greedy", meaning that if the regex matches both a smaller and larger part of the string, it will capture the larger part ([more about greedy regexes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)).

In Ruby (and most regex syntaxes), you can qualify your `+` quantifier with a `?` to make it non-greedy.  So your regex would become `/(?:\[\[(.+?)\]\])+/`.

However, you'll notice this still doesn't work for what you want to do. The Ruby capture groups just don't work inside a repeating group.  For your problem, you'll need to use [`scan`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-scan):

```
"[[a]][[ab]][[abc]]".scan(/\[\[(.+?)\]\]/).flatten
    => ["a", "ab", "abc"]
```