# Split on second comma in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, split, ruby-on-rails-5

Apologies for the "not so great questions". This happens when your eyes are closed but your brain keeps thinking about code.

This bit puzzles me. I want to split a string on a comma to make it an array, OR..., if I can send to my controller the array then perfect but anything I do never seem to work so what may work is to split on the second comma in a string.

I have a state array that looks like this:
[image]

So when I use `params[:file].split(",")` I get a handle error for `data:image/jpeg;base64` because it splits on the first comma when the code itself it correct. A stupid question, can you split on the second comma in ruby?

The array is like: `["data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/xxxxxx,data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/xxxxxx"]`

My input looks like this and I have tried many variations with `file[]`, `file[][]`

```
<input type="hidden" name="file" value={this.state.files} />
```

I've used `concat` to get the array.

Comment: ok, so looking at this, what you actually want is each substring in the string that starts with "data:" yes? does that help you find another solution?

Comment: Yes. No I have not find another solution. I'm all out of brain power, sorry.

Comment: How about using a rgex to match all the instances of "data:.*" ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27881549/ruby-regex-to-match-multiple-occurrences-of-pattern

Comment: A silver bullet for you `params[:file].gsub(',data', '|data').split('|')`

Comment: @LongNguyen Ok....works! But will the format of base64 change in the future?

Comment: @LongNguyen You should have posted your answer to get some credit as it worked.

Comment: Please replace the picture of your array with characters (without `0:`, `1:` and `[2]`) so readers can cut and paste. It's also helpful to assign a variable to each input object (e.g., `arr = ["data:...", "data:..."]`) so that readers can refer to those variables (here just one) in answers and comments.

Comment: The part that says "the array is like" should be enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also serialize the files array in a different manner before sending to Rails.

What does the code that sends files look like?

If anything, can you join it like this, with some unique separator?

```
makeRequest({ file: this.state.files.join('---') });
```

And then split with that in Ruby

```
params[:file].split('---')
```

Comment: Well, in react: `var files =  this.state.files.join('---');` then the input value would be `files`. Works. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. In general if you *have* to serialize something into string, it's way better to choose a separator that you know won't occur naturally. Perhaps a better way would be to send your params as JSON if it's a POST request, then you'll get array parsing for free.

Comment: It was post but i almost gave up as it wasn't working as expected. But your code saved the day.

Answer (score 1):

```
params[:files].split(",").each_slice(2).map { |top| "#{top.first},#{top.last}"}
```

Basically you can split by "," as normal but then merge every two elements together : )

```
str = '["data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/xxxxxx,data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/xxxxxx"]'
str.split(",").each_slice(2).map{ |top| "#{top.first},#{top.last}"}
 => ["[\"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/xxxxxx", "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/xxxxxx\"]"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result = []
incoming_data.gsub(/"data:\S+"/) {|member| result << member}
```

maybe this way...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12833543)

Comment: Should I remove my answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "Now is the time for citizens, every last one, to revolt, without delay."

i1 = str.index(',') 
i2 = i1 + 1 + str[i1+1..-1].index(',')
[str[0..i2-1], str[i2+1..-1]]
  # => ["Now is the time for citizens, every last one",
  #     "to revolt, without delay."]
```